# Can ADAMSync be used for data synchronization between "Non AD" directory server and AD LDS?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, directoryservices, ldif, adlds

If yes what could be the config file for this.

If no, what other tools can be used for syncing the data between OID and AD LDS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reesearch and tests I figured out that ADAMSync can only be used to sync the data between AD and AD LDS. It does not work with Oracle Internet Directory.